# Upgrading Spring with 3.1 to spring 4.0 applicationcontext.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to upgrade spring from version 3.1 to version 4.0. But i am getting an error on  RestApi :

```
14:11:00,286 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]

14:11:00,381 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: mvc-dispatcher-servet.xml

Comment: could paste the complete stacktrace, please ?

Comment: Please add your configuration.